# foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'double'

Tags: c#, dictionary, foreach

I'm new to both c# and using the Mathnet library, so I have the follwoing code, `BasicCandidate` is a class that has a function called `GetCScores()` which returns a `Dictionary< string, double>`. `classMeans`is just an array of `Vector<double>`

```
foreach (BasicCandidate bc in data) {
    int i = 0;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> score in bc.GetCScores()) {

      classMeans[bc.GetClassNumber()][++i] += score.Value;
    }
}
```

At the second `foreach`statement I'm getting an error that says:

`foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type double...`

I looked around online and some people pointed out that this happens when a dictionary is being modified, which is not allowed. But as you can see, I'm not doing that. Can anyone suggest a solution and explain why I'm getting this error?

Comment: If `bc.GetCScores` truly returned a `Dictionary< string, double>` your code would be fine, so it is unlikely it does. This message in no way relates to modifying a dictionary while enumerating it. Can you include the code for `GetCScores` in your question?

Comment: Show us the function `GetCScores`, at least the function header.

Comment: `public Dictionary<string, double> GetScores();`

Comment: @MrX You have given us `GetScores`, not `GetCScores`, are you simply calling the wrong function here?

Answer (score 3):

It appears `GetCScores` is actually returning a `double`, which does not implement have a `GetEnumerator` method, which is required for `foreach` (the most likely source of that method is something implementing `IEnumerable`).

It seems as though the method isn't returning `Dictionary<string, double>` or there is some code missing from the question that explains the problem further.

The advice you heard about the underlying collection being modified occurs when a collection being iterated is itself modified during the iteration. From the code you posted it appears you are not doing this.

Comment: `foreach` does not require an implementation of `IEnumerable`, it only requires that the object's type has a `GetEnumerator` method.

Comment: @dcastro I'll amend, thanks. Though I should have remembered that, the compiler plays that trick with other items too.